# Replacing Redux with Apollo for local state management

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo

I'm pretty new to GraphQL and Apollo but I've been using Redux along with React for the last 3 years. Based on Apollo documentation, they encourage developers to use it as the single source of truth:

> We want to be able to access boolean flags and device API results from
>   multiple components in our app, but don't want to maintain a separate
>   Redux or MobX store. Ideally, we would like the Apollo cache to be the
>   single source of truth for all data in our client application

I'm trying to figure out the way to replicate with Apollo what Redux would allow me. In my application, I have "Tags", an array of objects with close to 15 different fields each. They are used on 3 different sections of my app and each section shows specific "Tags" as well as specific fields from the "Tags". Based on that, the way I approach this with Redux is to fetch the "Tags" from my API, and, in the reducer, I create different arrays containing the IDs of the specific "Tags" I need for each section and I also create a Map (id, value) with the original data. It would be something like:

```
const tags = new Map(); //(tagId, tag) containing all the tags
const sectionATags = []; // array of ids for section A tags
const sectionBTags = []; // array of ids for section B tags
const sectionCTags = []; // array of ids for section C tags
```

My goal is to replicate the same behavior but, even though they encourage you to manage your local state using Apollo, I'm not sure if what I want to achieve is possible in a **simple way**, or if it is actually a **good practice** to do so with Apollo. I've been following [this example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/) from the docs and what they mainly do is adding or removing extra fields to the data received from the server by extending the query or mutating the cached data with the `@client` directive.

At the same time, I understand GraphQL was meant to query the specific data you need, instead of the typical REST request where you would get a big JSON with all the data regardless of whether you need it or not, but it feels like it wouldn't be efficient to do 3 different queries in this case with the specific data I need for each section.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or maybe Apollo is thought for "simpler local state management". Am I following the right path or shall I keep using Redux with another GraphQL library that just allows me to fetch data without a management layer?

Answer (score 0):

Apollo has normalized cache ... you can query once all [fields required anywhere] data - subsequent/additional queries can be "cache only". No additional requests will be made - it's safe if all required fields already exists.

Converting data structure ...usually not needed, we're working on data [and shape] we need ("not our but backend problem"). You can:

- change data shape in resolver [in graphql API wrapping REST],
- reshape data in REST-link (direct REST API access from Apollo),
- read data once at startup, save converted in local (all following queries reads local)

Common app state can be left in redux - data fetching should be in apollo.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if what I want to achieve is doable with Apollo. Rather than reshaping, I want to create new data structures based on the data I fetch from the server. Does it make sense to use Apollo for it or shall I keep using Redux?

Comment: still 3rd case ... extend/convert or save as separate types, all possible